# Apache - random outage

Tags: ubuntu, flask, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi, devops

Recently I have met new trouble with Apache. We have an app written in Python(3.5) in Flask(1.0.2) running on

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

We have two servers behind ELB (AWS Elasict Loadbalancer) and they suddenly (running on that configuration past 3 months) started to failing. I found that by Alarms from ELB and external tool for monitoring. We suddenly started to getting E408 (Timeout) and E503(Service Unavailable).

I started to digging to see what could be a cause, 
In apache logs I found lot of messsages (seems to be just before the fail) like this one:

```
[Mon Jun 25 22:27:04.613967 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1275:tid 139684390848256] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 1.2.3.4:2819] mod_wsgi (pid=1275): Unable to get bucket brigade for request., referer: https://xx.xx.xx/
```

I also queried syslog and saw this one:

```
Jun 25 22:13:25 my_hostname systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of ubuntu.
Jun 25 22:13:25 my_hostname systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Jun 25 22:13:25 my_hostname systemd[1]: Started Session 1424 of user ubuntu.
Jun 25 22:13:25 my_hostname systemd[6239]: Reached target Sockets.
Jun 25 22:13:25 my_hostname systemd[6239]: Reached target Timers.
Jun 25 22:13:25 my_hostname systemd[6239]: Reached target Paths.
Jun 25 22:13:25 my_hostname systemd[6239]: Reached target Basic System.
Jun 25 22:13:25 my_hostname systemd[6239]: Reached target Default.
Jun 25 22:13:25 my_hostname systemd[6239]: Startup finished in 8ms.
Jun 25 22:13:25 my_hostname systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Jun 25 22:14:47 my_hostname systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Apache2 web server...
Jun 25 22:14:47 my_hostname apache2[6624]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Jun 25 22:14:59 my_hostname apache2[6624]:  *
Jun 25 22:14:59 my_hostname systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jun 25 22:14:59 my_hostname systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Jun 25 22:14:59 my_hostname apache2[6660]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Jun 25 22:14:59 my_hostname apache2[6660]: AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for my_hostname
Jun 25 22:14:59 my_hostname apache2[6660]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Jun 25 22:15:00 my_hostname apache2[6660]:  *
Jun 25 22:15:00 my_hostname systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Its interesting that both servers (almost identical) failed at the same time (they were restarted about same time because of deploy of new version and traffic could be about the same for both, as they are behind one Load Balancer).

Already tried to find simillar problem, but had no luck so far.

One more interesting thing, I have found few messages like this one in the log:

```
[Mon Jun 25 22:27:04.657763 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1274:tid 139684507617024] [remote 172.31.12.149:720] mod_wsgi (pid=1274): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/my_app/app.wsgi'.
[Mon Jun 25 22:27:04.658503 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1274:tid 139684482414336] [remote 172.31.12.149:62417] mod_wsgi (pid=1274): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/my_app/app.wsgi'.
[Mon Jun 25 22:27:04.658528 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1274:tid 139684532819712] [remote 172.31.12.149:52139] mod_wsgi (pid=1274): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/my_app/app.wsgi'.
[Mon Jun 25 22:27:04.658584 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1274:tid 139684482414336] [remote 172.31.12.149:62417] OSError: failed to write data
[Mon Jun 25 22:27:04.658818 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1274:tid 139684516017920] [remote 172.31.12.149:208] OSError: failed to write data
[Mon Jun 25 22:27:04.659999 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1274:tid 139684532819712] [remote 172.31.12.149:52139] OSError: failed to write data
[Mon Jun 25 22:27:04.660411 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1274:tid 139684507617024] [remote 172.31.12.149:720] OSError: failed to write data
```

Not sure if it could be related or not, but I know for sure that we are canceling lot of request before they are finished (for reason).

Also we are running on Ubuntu + Flask (and more likely same setup) for years and we never had problem like that.

Really appreciate any idea, thanks!

Comment: What mod_wsgi configuration are you using? Are you using daemon mode of mod_wsgi and set up the required timeouts to have it auto recover in the case of lock ups? Are you forcing the use of the main Python interpreter by setting ``WSGIApplicationGroup`` to ``%{GLOBAL}`` to avoid lock up dues to third party C extensions for Python which do not work in sub interpreters. Really need to see your configuration.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton same problem we are facing and forcing the use of the main Python interpreter by setting `WSGIApplicationGroup` to `%{GLOBAL} `